# How to call an another agent from same database (replica) but different domino server?

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

**I do have the following situation:**

- `"ScheduledJobs.nsf"` with the agent `"Worker"` and agent `"RunOn_DominoServer2"`
- `"ScheduledJobs.nsf"` is replicated on **DominoServer1** and **DominoServer2**

**What I want to do is:**

- While the agent `"RunOn_DominoServer2"` on **DominoServer1** is running, it should start the agent `"Worker"` on **DominoServer2**

**My Code:**

```
Dim agent As NotesAgent
Dim sess As New NotesSession    
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument    

Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase   
Set agent = sess.CurrentAgent

Call db.Open( "DominoServer2/ORGANIZATION", "ScheduledJobs.nsf" )
Set agent = db.GetAgent("Worker")

// Reason why im using 'run' insted of RunOnServer:
// https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO42549
If agent.Run() = 0 Then
    Print "SUCCESS"
Else
```

**Problem:**

When I run the code there is the following error in console:
DIIOP Server: Agent 'RunOn_DominoServer2' error: This database object is already open as D:..(path of the db)..\ScheduledJobs.nsf

**Question:**

How can I connect to the same database on a different Domino Server and run an agent without issue? Reason: I have to run an agent, which has to be run locally on the target server.

Comment: The error message references DIIOP. If the agent is running on the server, it should not be using DIIOP to connect to the other server. Why are you using NCSO.jar instead of notes.jar in an agent?

Comment: The initial connection goes trough a DIIOP connection, which starts the agent. But however the error its the same, even I start the agent manually over IBM Domino Designer. The agent is written in Lotus Script. The message is the same, only difference is that there is no DIIOP Server" at the beginning.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like something else ScheduledJobs.nsf open and locked for exclusive use. Can you open ScheduledJobs.nsf on DominoServer2 from a Notes client -- and not a local Notes client installed on DominoServer2. If it's nothing in your agent, then it could be literally anything else that has access to the Data directory on DomionServer2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the other database as a mail-in database, so then you can send a mail with commands and/or data to trigger your Worker agent.